# Prove that there doesn't exist a polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients such that $P(2)=P(-2)=2$ and $P(0)=0$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, integers

Stumbled upon this problem in a math competition. Couldn't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Please show attempt

Comment: Hint: What are the known roots of the polynomial $Q(x)=P(x)-2$? What does this tell you about possible factors of $Q(x)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $P(0)=0$ we have $P(X)=XQ(X)$. Then $P(2)+P(-2)=4$ which is equivalent to $Q(2)-Q(-2)=2$.

Now recall that $m-n\mid Q(m)-Q(n)$. For $m=2$ and $n=-2$ we get $4\mid 2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We might also make an argument using function symmetries.  Since $ \ P(0) \ = \ 0 \ , $ the polynomial has zero "constant term", so it may be written as $$ P(x) \ \ = \ \ a_nx^n \ + \ a_{n-1}x^{n-1} \ + \ a_{n-2}x^{n-2} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_2x^2 \ + \ a_1x \ \ ,  $$
with the coefficients taken to be integers.

We are given the values of the function $ \ P(2) \ = \ P(-2) \ = \ 2 \ \ . \ $  ***If*** $ \ P(x) \ $ has even symmetry, then we have
$$ P(\pm 2) \ \ = \ \ a_n·2^n \ +  \ a_{n-2}·2^{n-2} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_2·2^2   \ \ = \ \ 2  \ \ , \ \ n \ \ \text{even} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   a_n·2^{n-1} \ +  \ a_{n-2}·2^{n-3} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_2·2 $$ $$ =   \ \  2  ·  [ \ a_n·2^{n-2} \ +  \ a_{n-2}·2^{n-4} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_2 \ ]    \ \  = \ \ 1 \ \ ,  $$
with the left side of the equation being some integer multiple of $ \ 2 \ \ , $ which is clearly not possible.  (It becomes clear why the constant term was "removed" for this problem.)

*Must* $ \ P(x) \ $   be an even function? If we write the polynomial function as a sum of even- and odd-symmetry functions, $ \ P(x) \ = \ P_e(x) + P_o(x) \ \ , $ then of course $ \ P_o(0) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ but also $ P_o(-2) \ = \ -P_o(2) \ = \ 0 \ \   $ [the odd-symmetry function makes zero contribution at these values of $ \ x \ \ ; $ this is related to **TonyK**'s comment on the OP]. Hence,
$$ P_o(-2) \ \ = \ \ a_{n-1}·(-2)^{n-1} \ +  \ a_{n-3}·(-2)^{n-3} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_1·(-2)     $$
$$ = \ \ -P_o(2) \ \ = \ \ -[ \ a_{n-1}·2^{n-1} \ +  \ a_{n-3}·2^{n-3} \ + \ \cdots \ + \ a_1·2 \ ]  \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \   \ \ (n \ \ \text{even}) \ \ .  $$
This requires that $ \ a_{n-1} \ = \ -a_{n-1} \ \ , \  \ a_{n-3} \ = \ -a_{n-3}  \ \ , \ \ \cdots \ \ , \ \  a_1 \ = \ -a_1 \ \ , $ so all of the odd coefficients of $ \ P(x) \ $ are zero.  Thus, $ \ P(x) \ $  *is*  an even function and the argument in the previous paragraph stands.  [We can see that the proposition may be generalized as:  there is no polynomial $ \ P(x) \ $ with integer coefficients for which $ \ P(k) \ = \ P(-k) \ = \ k \ $ and $ \ P(0) \ = \ 0 \ , \ $ with $ \ k \ $ being an integer.]